# Is $F(x) = \int_a^{g(x)} f(t)g(t)h(t) dt$ increasing on [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I believe the answer to be yes.  Since f is continuous it must be bounded...
but not sure why it is increasing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the chain rule we have
$$F'(x)=f(g(x))g'(x)\ge0$$
since $f$ is non-negative and $g$ is increasing so $F$ is increasing.